# Ruby on Rails / Heroku - The page you were looking for doesn't exist

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku

I realise this is a very common question but I am currently teaching myself ruby on rails and after going through the gargantuan task of getting an app set up on Heroku I've encountered my first problem.

I thought something was broken since when I click the `About your application's environment` link I get the `page not found error` but read that's ok as that should only work in the dev environment.

So, I went ahead and created a controller and a view with the following command:

```
rails generate controller Index
```

In my `app > controllers` folder I have a file called `index_controller.rb` which contains the following:

```
class IndexController < ApplicationController
  def index
  end
end
```

and in my `app > views > index` folder I have a file named `index.html.erb`

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Test Site</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Test</h1>
    </body>
</html>
```

But when I visit http://safe-peak-2383.herokuapp.com/index/index/ I get the page not found error.

Since I'm using Heroku my gem file contains this:

```
group :development, :test do
  gem 'sqlite3'
end
group :production do
  gem 'pg'
end
```

Any ideas?

Comment: can you visit the page on your local machine in dev. mode?

Comment: Did you make a corresponding route? Did you push your changes?

Comment: Whe are you accessing index twice (.../index/index/)? Shouldn't the page be http://safe-peak-2383.herokuapp.com/index? I tried that and it takes me to the generic Rails page. Did you follow the directions on that page and remove the default index.html?

Comment: sorry, the names aren't very good but I was under the impression the url strucure in rails was `http://appurl:300/controller/view/`. Not actually checked locally on dev and don't think I've added a new route nor removed the default one, I will take a look and try to figure those bits out

Comment: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html

Comment: pay attention to the stack trace in dev mode. it will help a lot, trust me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you visit http://safe-peak-2383.herokuapp.com you will see the getting started page. I seems like you have not set the root route for your app.

first,

```
git rm public/index.html
```

This will get rid of the getting started page when you visit the root path of your app

next, in `config/routes.rb`

```
root to: 'index#index'
```

This will make http://safe-peak-2383.herokuapp.com show the index of your index controller.

Remember to push all these changes to github then heroku for them to take effect

Comment: thanks, tried what you said but http://safe-peak-2383.herokuapp.com/ still shows the getting started page :/

Comment: no problem, glad to help. Stick with it and it will become second nature with a little experience